# How to show plot lines in the legend in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I not only want my legend to contain series' names, I also want it to contain name of my other items like my plotline. Here is my code:

```
plotLines: [
    {
        color: 'red',
        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
        value: response.AverageTime,
        width: 2,
        label: {
            text: response.PlotLineName, 
            x: +10, 
            y: +30,
            rotation: 360,
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
]
```

So I want my plotline's name which is "Average Velocity Deviation" looks like in the legend box like below. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create an empty series which mimics the characteristics of the plot line (color, dash style...). You can then optionally use the `legendItemClick` event to "link it up" to the plot line.

For example, you predefine these variables for ID and plot line options:

```
plotLineId = 'myPlotLine'; // To identify for removal

// Plot line options for adding
plotLineOptions = {
    color: '#FF0000',
    id: plotLineId, 
    width: 2,
    value: 5.5,
    dashStyle: 'shortdash'
};
```

Your axis plotline:

```
xAxis: {
    plotLines: [ plotLineOptions ]
}
```

Your mimic series:

```
series: [
    // ...
    {
        // Series that mimics the plot line
        color: '#FF0000',
        name: 'My plotline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        events: {
            // Event for showing/hiding plot line
            legendItemClick: function(e) {
                if(this.visible) {
                    this.chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine(plotLineId);
                }
                else {
                    this.chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine(plotLineOptions);
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/m8qxu1tz/) of how it works (or [this minimal example](https://jsfiddle.net/7qvaybcn/), without events).

Comment: Ultimate solution, hats off!!

Comment: Great solution.   One little caveat:  I had to make the type of the fake series different than my other actual data series.   I had a column series and when I added the fake series, it shrank my columns to half their width (I assume to make room for the fake series).   However, if I specified a different type (I used 'line'), the column width of my actual data series stays the same.   Functionality still worked well.

Comment: Here's [an example with multiple plotlines](https://jsfiddle.net/oqLu6cdx/1/)

When storing your plotlines inside an array, you specifically need to spread them when passing them to `xAxis.plotlines: [...myplotlines]` otherwise Highcharts consumes them, and you won't be able toggle them on/off in the legend because they won't exist!

Answer (score 14):

Just as an alternative, if you're going to go so far as to make a fake series that mimics all of the aspects of your plot line...

You can just use that series *as* your `plotLine`, and skip all of the extra work of tying everything together...

like:

```
{  
  name: 'Plot Line',
  color: 'red',
  type:'line',
  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
  lineWidth: 2,
  data: [[minXvalue, plotLineValue], {x:maxXvalue, y:plotLineValue, dataLabels: { enabled: true }}]
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/74/

Comment: great solution...more concise